# Facebook login integration with phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm new using facebook for developers, I want to use Facebook Login for my app developed in phonegap, where I want that when users want to login, it opens facebook standard page for them to continue with the process and return data to my app. But the first thing I found was that there were many solutions:

The Login Flow for iOS
The Login Flow for Android
The Login Flow for Web (without JavaScript SDK)

But none for what I want. I also found facebook github's solutions but, it seems to be only for Android or iOs, but not both of them:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

So I have some doubts:
¿What solution should I use for phonegap integration?
I know that I need an app-id that I can find it at facebook's developers page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/ , but if that key is locally saved, at the devices, would it be safe?

Thanks